# Can I find out how many times a particular hat has been awarded?

Tags: discussion, statistics, winter-bash

I'd like to know how many people got a given hat (especially the [secret ones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats#304345)!).

This might also answer the question: which is the most difficult hat to get?

Is that statistics disclosed at the end of the Winter Bash? (I didn't follow the closely the previous years.)

Comment: PS: it must be 7pm somewhere...

Comment: I don't know about any way of finding out how many people have a certain hat, but you can find out what hat is the rarest on the [network-wide leaderboard](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network). The hats of each user there are ordered with the rarest first, so it's very likely that the first hat in the list of the #1 user's hats is the rarest (in this case "Waffles").

Comment: Also, regarding your 7PM comment, if you're trying to get the Hero of Time hat, there aren't hats on per-site metas (at least not this year, but I really hope there will be next year).

Comment: @DonaldDuck Daaamn! That wasn"t clear at all... Also thanks for the tip on the leaderboard I wondered about that order.

Comment: Whoa the rep cap is easier to get than "It’s-a me!", weird.

Comment: So that's why I havent received a Just Jesting hat. Bah humbug.

Comment: @TinyGiant you're not witty enough, sorry.